# How to check whether the phone supports RTP

Tags: java-me, rtp

I want to know whether a device/mobile phone supports RTP,RTCP. Here is how I currently check

```
 String ar [] =Manager.getSupportedProtocols(null);
    for (int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
     System.out.println("Supported Protocols are :"+ar[i]);
    }
```

I use NetBeans IDE and in 6.1 gives for above code

```
http
file
device
capture
```

and later versions (6.7 etc )gives  `rtsp https` including above protocols. 
My question is that the way I check  is correct?

Other question is that
    rtsp has rtp and rtcp.but when I try to create a socket connection which waits for rtp packets,an exception throws

```
 javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: ConnectionNotFound error in
```

socket::open : error = 10051\n

For creating a socket connection and to get a stream I use `StreamConnectionNotifier`  Here is how I do it;

```
(StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open("socket://xxx.xx.xx.xx:4040", Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
```

The api says an exception which I mentioned above can be thrown if the protocol is not supported.

Can't I receive rtp even-though the phone supports rtsp?